# tidyr/dplyr - spreading multiple variables for duplicate ids

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have some awfully dirty data that I'm really struggling to clean. An example of the issue is below:

```
ID    NAME    ADDRESS               EMAIL     PHN
1   Alice 123 Street     alice@gmail.com 5555555
1   Alice 123 Street                <NA> 4444444
2     Bob   9 Circle       Bob@gmail.com 1111111
3 Charlie      4 Ave   Charlie@gmail.com 3333333
3 Charlie      4 Ave Charlie@hotmail.com 3333333
3 Charlie      4 Ave                <NA>      NA
4    Doug    1 Court                <NA> 6666666
```

The desired output is something like this:

```
ID    NAME    ADDRESS           EMAIL_1             EMAIL_2   PHN_1   PHN_2
1   Alice 123 Street   alice@gmail.com                <NA> 5555555 4444444
2     Bob   9 Circle     bob@gmail.com                <NA> 1111111      NA
3 Charlie      4 Ave charlie@gmail.com charlie@hotmail.com 3333333      NA
4    Doug    1 Court              <NA>                <NA> 6666666      NA
```

With the understanding that there can be an arbitrary expansion of the `EMAIL` and `PHN` variables (i.e., there might be *n* repetitions of ID that have different (or `NA`) values.)

My solution thus far:

```
df.test <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(EMAILID = paste0("EMAIL_",row_number())) %>%
  spread(EMAILID,EMAIL) %>%
  mutate(PHONEID = paste0('PHN_',row_number())) %>%
  spread(PHONEID,PHN)
```

But this produces an even more malformed data.frame:

```
ID    NAME    ADDRESS           EMAIL_1             EMAIL_2 EMAIL_3   PHN_1   PHN_2 PHN_3
1   Alice 123 Street   alice@gmail.com                <NA>    <NA> 5555555      NA    NA
1   Alice 123 Street              <NA>                <NA>    <NA>      NA 4444444    NA
2     Bob   9 Circle     Bob@gmail.com                <NA>    <NA> 1111111      NA    NA
3 Charlie      4 Ave Charlie@gmail.com                <NA>    <NA> 3333333      NA    NA
3 Charlie      4 Ave              <NA> Charlie@hotmail.com    <NA>      NA 3333333    NA
3 Charlie      4 Ave              <NA>                <NA>    <NA>      NA      NA    NA
4    Doug    1 Court              <NA>                <NA>    <NA> 6666666      NA    NA
```

Any help? I suspect that my issue is something to do with the `spread()` command, but my attempts so far have proven pretty fruitless. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you take the mutates out?

Comment: @RyanMorton: if I replace the code with:

```df.test <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  spread(ID,EMAIL) %>%
  spread(ID,PHN)```

I get Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (4,5)

Comment: Hm, could you add NAME to the group_by?

Comment: Results in the same error, unfortunately. Same thing if I try with ADDRESS.

Comment: How about a `summarise_each(funs(first)` at the piped to the end of the original?

Comment: or maybe `summarise_each(funs(max)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `summarize` not `mutate`, then use `separate` to split the results. To do this dynamically you can determine the number of distinct email and phone groups to use ahead of time, use `separate_` and then set `fill = right` to remove the warnings.  The last two `mutate` statements are there to clean up `NA` values turned into strings.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cols <- cols <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(PHN), !is.na(EMAIL)) %>% 
  group_size() %>% 
  max()

df %>%
  group_by(ID, NAME, ADDRESS) %>%
  summarize_each(funs(toString(unique(.[!is.na(.)]))), EMAIL, PHN) %>% 
  separate_("EMAIL", sprintf("EMAIL%s", 1:cols), sep = ",", fill = "right") %>% 
  separate_("PHN", sprintf("PHN%s", 1:cols), sep = ",", fill = "right") %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, trimws) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., grep("NA", .), NA)))

  Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
Groups: ID, NAME [4]

     ID    NAME    ADDRESS            EMAIL1              EMAIL2    PHN1    PHN2
  <int>  <fctr>     <fctr>             <chr>               <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1     1   Alice 123 Street   alice@gmail.com                <NA> 5555555 4444444
2     2     Bob   9 Circle     Bob@gmail.com                <NA> 1111111    <NA>
3     3 Charlie      4 Ave Charlie@gmail.com Charlie@hotmail.com 3333333    <NA>
4     4    Doug    1 Court              <NA>                <NA> 6666666    <NA>
```

The warnings will be thrown

Comment: Does this throw numerous errors to you? The output is correct, but I received this list of errors when running:
```Warning messages:
1: Too many values at 1 locations: 3 
2: Too few values at 2 locations: 2, 4 
3: Too many values at 1 locations: 3 
4: Too few values at 2 locations: 2, 4 ```

Comment: You'll get warnings, not errors.  The warnings are referencing to the extra items produced by some combinations being greater than the number of split columns.  See `?separate` and look at my note regarding `separate_`

Answer (score 0):

**1) reshape** Using base R this can be done in 3 lines. The first  line of code adds a sequence number for each `ID` and the last performs the transformation from long to wide.  The second line of code reshapes the data frame from long to wide and the last line of code removes an columns that contain only NAs. (If columns of NAs are unlikely or you don't mind them then the third line of code could be omitted.)

```
df2 <- transform(df.test, seq = ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq_along))
df2 <- reshape(df2, dir = "wide", timevar = "seq", idvar = c("ID", "NAME", "ADDRESS"))
subset(df2, select = !apply(is.na(df.test2), 2, all))
```

giving:

```
  ID    NAME    ADDRESS           EMAIL.1   PHN.1             EMAIL.2   PHN.2
1  1   Alice 123 Street   alice@gmail.com 5555555                <NA> 4444444
3  2     Bob   9 Circle     Bob@gmail.com 1111111                <NA>      NA
4  3 Charlie      4 Ave Charlie@gmail.com 3333333 Charlie@hotmail.com 3333333
7  4    Doug    1 Court              <NA> 6666666                <NA>      NA
```

**2) magrittr** The same code except formed into a magrittr pipeline could be written:

```
library(magrittr)

df.test %>%
   transform(seq = ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq_along)) %>%
   reshape(dir = "wide", timevar = "seq", idvar = c("ID", "NAME", "ADDRESS")) %>%
   subset(select = !apply(is.na(.), 2, all))
```

**Note:**  The input `df.test` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
ID,NAME,ADDRESS,EMAIL,PHN
1,Alice,123 Street,alice@gmail.com,5555555
1,Alice,123 Street,NA,4444444
2,Bob,9 Circle,Bob@gmail.com,1111111
3,Charlie,4 Ave,Charlie@gmail.com,3333333
3,Charlie,4 Ave,Charlie@hotmail.com,3333333
3,Charlie,4 Ave,NA,
4,Doug,1 Court,NA,6666666"
df.test <- read.csv(text=Lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone concerned about deprecation warnings with `summarize_each`, the following code works with currently supported functions:

```
df.test %>% 
  group_by(ID, NAME, ADDRESS) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(EMAIL, PHN), funs(toString(unique(.[!is.na(.)])))) %>%
  separate(EMAIL, sprintf('EMAIL%s', 1:cols), sep = ",", fill = 'right') %>%
  separate(PHN, sprintf('PHN%s', 1:cols), sep = ",", fill = 'right') %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, trimws) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., grep("NA", .), NA)))
```